# Energy levels of combined orbitals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure

I saw the MO diagram for a NH3 molecule but couldn't understand why the combined atomic orbitals were in the positions they were, and if these positions were fixed.

[image]

Why is the sigma anti bonding lower in energy than the pi anti-bonding? Is it something you have to learn off by heart for each common molecule?

Comment: This diagram is very awful. It mixes hybridisation and group orbitals, which does not make sense. In a way it is mixing MO theory and VB theory, but in the worst possible way...

Comment: @Martin-マーチン do you have a book/chapter recommendation where it is explained better?

Comment: hav not read, but looks better: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Advanced_Inorganic_Chemistry/NH3_Molecular_Orbitals This looks quite correct: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NH3_MO.png Basic texts on quantum chemistry should cover this in detail... see [Resources for learning Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37303/4945)

Answer (score 2):

In the strictest sense, the orbital energies are simply eigenvalues of the multi-electron Schrödinger equation; unfortunately, the multi-electron Hamiltonian takes a nasty form and is [impossible](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/09%3A_The_Electronic_States_of_the_Multielectron_Atoms/9.01%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation_For_Multi-Electron_Atoms) for us to solve exactly, so we can't get any insight on the energies from *that* approach...

Instead we inadvertently resort to [LCAO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination_of_atomic_orbitals)-based methods, whereby exploiting symmetry the interacting atomic (or symmetry) orbitals can form molecular orbitals of the correct form. The energy of these is another issue; for some back-of-the-envelope calculations, severe approximations such as Hückel MO theory can be useful for a rough idea, but more accurate estimates just require much more complicated computational methods (*e.g.* the acclaimed Hartree-Fock).

As these methods resort to a large basis of AOs (and not just the simplified 2 AOs mix in- and out-of-phase to give 2 MOs picture) and other complications such as [electron correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_correlation), I'm afraid there is no simple rule to give an accurate enough estimate unless thorough calculations are made. So, to forwardly answer your question, rather impractically we can't know *a priori* the ordering of the orbitals in the general case.

Certain semi-empirical rules (based on the experience from multiple common systems and "chemical intuition") exist, such as the (often useful) approximation formulated for organic molecules $\sigma < \pi < l.p. < \pi^* <\sigma^*$ though this is *very* rough and suitable for organic systems, usually.

In the case of ammonia (as given in the question) a particular ordering is found; it should be noted that the two types of bonding interactions are both $\sigma$-interactions (*i.e.* locally cylindrically symmetric; there is no nodal plane within each individual bond). Despite the double degeneracy, the $e$ set still constitutes a $\sigma$-type MO (with a node in the overall MO shape, rationalising a higher energy than the $a_1$); so the ordering in ammonia is $\sigma_{a_1} < \sigma_e < lp_{a_1} < \sigma_{a_1}^* < \sigma_e^*$ -not so counter-intuitive after all, just different types of $\sigma$ MOs possessing different energies. (As a sidenote, the doubly deg. $\sigma_e^*$ are those allowing ammonia to act as a weak [$\pi$-acceptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_backbonding), placing it higher than simple $\sigma$-donors in the spectrochemical series.)

***Summary***: MO energy calculation especially in polyatomic species is *hard* and done with complex computational methods. Unfortunately, then, we can't have a general rule for the energy ordering in advance. However, often we can make educated guesses in analogy to systems we have already seen.

(For a more detailed look into the methods used to obtain the energies see Atkins & Friedman *Molecular Quantum Mechanics*, 4th ed.; Chapters 8–9)